# how to calc the accurate height of TableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

now i calc the height of TableViewCell like this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

but i found that its not accurate because there are line spaces within it.that is when you got more lines,there will be higher white space.

so how do you guys calc the height?

thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I dont use the method you use, I do this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;    
    YourCustomCell *yourCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCustomCell"];
    cell = yourCustomCell;    
    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

Comment: but `heightForRowAtIndexPath` executed before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you correct height for your cell.

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
       return size.height;
    }
```

Comment: So what you wanna exactly... ? You can't return height for particular cell without this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f // if you are using iPhone
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 20.0f // if you are using iPhone
#define FONT_SIZE 16.0f // if you are using iPhone


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CGFloat height = MAX([[yourArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height, 44.0f)+ (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 1.5);


return height;
}
```